How to add or control relationships between tables in Clickhouse?
As I understand, there's no relationships between tables in clikhouse.
So how I need to check data to be sure that querys with join will works right?
Here by tables:
CREATE TABLE db.categories
(
    category_id     UInt16 not null,
    category_name   String,
    primary key (category_id)
)
ENGINE = MergeTree;


CREATE TABLE db.services
(
    service_id  UInt16 not null,
    category_id UInt16 not null,
    primary key (service_id)
)
ENGINE = MergeTree;


ClickHouse is not a relational database system. Probably ClickHouse does not fit to you requirements. If you design data model with relation approach it will not work good in ClickHouse in most cases. Instead of joins it is much better to keep all related data in the same table.
